# Navigating directly to the second tab in tab navigator

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, viewstack

I have a component mxml in which i have a save button, on click of the save button i need to display another component which will be in a tab navigator, for this I am using the view stack. My problem is, on click of save I need to display the second tab instead of the first tab, but defaultly the first tab will be displayed.

How could this be accomplished?

Thanks!

cheers,

Deena

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TabNavigator and ViewStack have an attribute "selectedIndex" which you can set to 1.

Comment: Vote the answer up and select it as the correct answer if it helped you, Deena.